# Is this an abscess on this cat? What to do?

Tags: cats, injury

Here's a link to view the image as I don't think stack exchange is letting me; https://ibb.co/ndO3Oz

The cat is not mine but is my neighbours unfortunately the neighbour is not in town and I fear quite neglectful of the cat. The cat has a wounded tail from a suspected cat fight. She is constantly licking it.

Since she is not my cat I can't afford the vet bills.

Answer (score 5):

Please note: **I'm not a vet.**

The wound doen't look badly infected, so there should be no need to rush to the vet. Flushing the wound with antiseptic is a good idea, but please be aware that the sudden pain can lead to the cat attacking you.

Honey has been used for thausands of years as antiseptic. It creates a germ-repelling barrier like a band aid.

> Some experts recommend that cats avoid honey altogether, but others argue that there is no clear toxicity to cats, and honey does have a number of potentially beneficial nutrients [...] Despite the potential risks to your cat’s digestive health, it is likely safe to give your cat 1/2 teaspoon of honey per day, particularly when using it for medicinal purposes. ([Source](https://www.organicfacts.net/can-cats-eat-honey.html))

Many cats seem to dislike the taste, but you should take into account that she could lick it off very soon. Also have in mind that the sweet smell might lure flys, bees and wasps to the cat.

I would suggest flushing the wound with antiseptics, then (if she didn't run off) take a few drops of honey out the jar, dip your fingertip in it and nudge her wound with the honeyed finger. Don't smear the stuff all over her.

Comment: She probably licked it raw again, but don't wory too much